# Build Java entire project jar using JDeveloper

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar, jdeveloper

I am using JDeveloper 11g to develop a desktop application. I want to make entire project jar which is run-able in java environment.. if I use only standard Java library jar works fine but my project contains external library like JfreeChart, Comm, Hibernate3 etc etc... when I try to make jar Its shows errors how can I make entire jar of my projects along with external library's.

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Please follow the below instructions..

> 1. Right-click project and select properties.
> 2. Click on Deployment, setup new Deployment by entering Deployment Profile type and name.
> 3. Now edit Deployment profile on screen.
> 4. Select Jar Options and specify your `main` class.

**If you have 3rd party jar then follow**

> 5. Select File group the click on New.
> 6. Select Dependency Analysis and Ok.
> 7. Then select the Contributors under new file group you have created.
>
>    1. Files tab for Files
>    2. Libraries tab for Libraries, Include the Libraries you using in your project.
> 8. Then Ok.

**If you don't have 3rd party jar then ignore the above**

> 10. Then right-click on project, select the profile under deploy.
> 11. Then Click finish to start deployment.

After finish deployment you see the jar in your project/deployment folder.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do  so. Have a look here - [Java create standalone jar with external jars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218966/java-create-standalone-jar-with-external-jars) and also here - [Put external library to the JAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034180/put-external-library-to-the-jar)

The simple way is to use a tool, but you can use ant too, to recompile a set of JAR's into one big-fat JAR.