# Deploying Java Library-Maven dependent artifacts on OSB

Tags: java, maven, aws-sdk, pom.xml, osb

I am new to OSB. I had this requirement where i needed to call Amazon SDK Java Code to execute, in order to call a SQS queue.

I used a Java CallOut, by generating a jar file that consumes AWS SDK using pom/maven dependencies. Everything is good till here. In fact I have individually already tested the SDK code as well to see if anything fails.

While trying to include the same into OSB Code, i include the newly created jar from its file location. So far so good. No errors in including in JDeveloper as well.

But when i deploy the same, i start to face issues. The deployment fails stating that the method that i selected for Java CallOut doesnt exist. It simply fails to recognize any library that is added via Maven as a dependency.

Is there anything that I am missing..??

How can i make OSB deployer resolve dependencies at time of deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240703/build-java-entire-project-jar-using-jdeveloper). It explains how to create a "fat"-Jar which will contain all your required dependencies.